# 'make' command error when compiling computer algebra system LiE

Tags: makefile, terminal, compiler-errors, gnu-make, symbolic-math

I'm trying to build [LiE](http://wwwmathlabo.univ-poitiers.fr/%7Emaavl/LiE/).

When I run `make`, I get the following error:

```
(base) [my name]-MacBook-Air-4:~ [my name]$ cd lie
(base) [my name]-MacBook-Air-4:lie [my name]$ make/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make math_functions binding_functions
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C box allgcc -c -ansi -I/Users/[my name]/lie -I/Users/[my name]/lie/box -O altdom.c
In file included from altdom.c:1:
In file included from /Users/[my name]/lie/lie.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/string.h:184:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/strings.h:73:7: error: redefinition of 'index' as different kind of symbolchar *index(const char *, int) __POSIX_C_DEPRECATED(200112L);^
/Users/[my name]/lie/lie.h:6:14: note: previous definition is heretypedef long index;^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [altdom.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [math_functions] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

The README file mentions the GNU C-compiler gcc, which I assume I don't have. Where can I download this, and is there anything I need to do after downloading it (such as putting it in a certain folder)? I also downloaded Bison (and maybe Xcode? Something popped up from Apple when I first tried to 'make' and I downloaded that). But after downloading these, I didn't put them anywhere.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question and formatted the output as a code block (three backticks) instead of a long set of monotype font text (one backtric).  It looks like the program you're trying to compile was never ported to MacOS and it uses the same function name internally as one of the C runtime functions.  It has nothing to do with the compiler.  If you really want to try to fix it you can edit the `lie.h` file and change the symbol `index` to something else, then change everywhere else in the code that uses that `index` symbol to the new value.  That might help.

Comment: `index()` is a BSD function, so it's not surprising to find it in the runtime library on BSD-derived MacOS.  It was once standardized in POSIX, its specifications have since been removed.

Comment: There may be a compiler option that will resolve the issue.  With `gcc`, setting any of the strict-conformance language modes seems to resolve its version of the same diagnostic.  Although you're more than likely using Clang rather than GCC, the same may still work.  For software of that vintage, the appropriate option would be [`-std=c90` or maybe `-std=c99`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#cmdoption-std).  That would go among the C compiler flags.

Comment: @MadScientist This worked! Thank you so much